# Jquery .change() event issue

Tags: php, jquery, events, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes constructed after performing an ajax call. When I try to reference their ids to do .change() event, the event won't trigger. Any ideas? Here is my code:

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({                        
    url:"../includes/MC.Admin.ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: empupdatedata,
    success: function(empupdate) {              
    var empupdateJson = $.parseJSON(empupdate);

                  $("#empupdateinfo_tbl").html(empupdateJson.updateempinfo);

                $("#empemploymentupdateinfo_tbl").html(empupdateJson.updateempemploymentinfo);


                $('#employee-update').bPopup({
                    modalClose: false
                });

                }
        });
```

This is where the textbox is constructed:

```
if($rm5->isbonus == 1 && $rm5->isallowance == 0)
{
    $updateemployeeemploymentinfo .= "<tr><td class = 'tbl_data'>
    Additional Payment</td><td>Bonus <input type = 'checkbox' 
    name = 'isbonus' id = 'uisbonus'> Allowance <input type = 'checkbox' 
    name = 'isallowanece' id = 'uisallowance'></td></tr><tr></tr>"; 
}
```

I want to use the id's of those two check boxes to trigger a change event using the following codes:

```
$("#uisbonus").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        $('#uamountcon').append("<td id = 'uamountcon'><input type = 'text' id = 'uamount ></td>")

    }
    else
    {
         $('#uamountcon').html();
    }
});

$("#uisallowance").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        $('#uamountcon').append("<td id = 'uamountcon'><input type = 'text' id = 'uamount ></td>")
    }
    else
    {
         $('#uamountcon').html();
    }
});//I placed this code insidethe $(document).ready(function() { });
```

Is the position of the change event wrong? Where should I put the event? Or what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: do you get an error in the console? When do you expect it to fire?

Comment: Either move the change event binding to directly after the elements are added to the page (within the ajax succes), or bind the events using `.delegate` or `.on` with the delegation syntax.

Comment: Your question is missing information about _when_ you try to bind the handlers. It might be that you bind before you actually insert the elements. You might want to take a look at jquerys live() method or its successor.

Comment: can you also confirm that the `id` is unique? if you have more than one element with the same `id`, I am pretty sure jQuery will ignore them.

Comment: My bad, the ajax call is triggered after clicking an .live click event. No errors when I try to inspect element at chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding them after the page has loaded you will have to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for event delegation.  `on()` was added in 1.7, however, for prior versions `delegate()` is the most effective means to use event delegation.

```
$("body").delegate("#uisbonus", "change", function(){ 
...
$("body").delegate("#uisallowance", "change", function(){
```

It may be better to reference a `class` instead of an `id`:

```
$("body").delegate(".uiClassName", "change", function(){
```

Comment: Should I place the code at the document.ready? or After the ajax call? Doesn't seem to work when placed inside the document.ready.

Comment: Technically it doesn't matter, but you can place it in your `$(document).ready(function(){...});` declaration.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks! Another question regarding my post. Why do you think is the reason why the appending of the table data is not being triggered? Thanks

Comment: The code here: `$('#uamountcon').append("<td id = 'uamountcon'><input type = 'text' id = 'uamount ></td>")`?

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation would be the easiest fix,

```
$(document).delegate("#uisbonus","change",function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        $('#uamountcon').append("<td id = 'uamountcon'><input type = 'text' id = 'uamount ></td>")

    }
    else
    {
         $('#uamountcon').html();
    }
});

$(document).delegate("#uisallowance","change",function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        $('#uamountcon').append("<td id = 'uamountcon'><input type = 'text' id = 'uamount ></td>")
    }
    else
    {
         $('#uamountcon').html();
    }
});
```